# Symmetric set difference and odd number of sets containing x

Tags: combinatorics, induction, alternative-proof

Let $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n$ be non-empty sets, $n\in\Bbb N$.
$$x\in A_1\triangle A_2\triangle\ldots\triangle A_n\;\iff x\text{ is in an odd number of sets}$$

In the script, this was proven by mathematical induction, but I have another question. Link to a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056042/prove-through-induction-that-a-in-a-1-triangle-a-2-triangle-ldots-triangle?rq=1)

**(1)** base $$n=1, \;x\in A_1 \iff \; x\text{ is in an odd number of sets}$$

**(3)** the assumption: the statement $$x\in A_1\triangle A_2\triangle\ldots\triangle A_n\;\iff x\text{ is in an odd number of sets}$$ is true for some number $n\in \mathbb N.$

**(3)** step of the induction:

$\begin{aligned}x\in A_1\triangle A_2\triangle\ldots\triangle A_n\triangle A_{n+1}&\\\iff\left(x\in A_1\triangle A_2\triangle\ldots\triangle A_n\;\land x\notin A_{n+1}\right)&\\\lor\left(x\notin A_1\triangle A_2\triangle\ldots\triangle A_n\;\land x\in A_{n+1}\right)
\\\left(x\text{ is in an odd number of sets }A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n\;\land x\notin A_{n+1}\right)&\\\lor\left(x\text{ is in an even number of sets }A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_n\land x\in A_{n+1}\right)\end{aligned}$

Now, when I have this in mind, how can I prove it without induction? Is there any other way?

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056042/prove-through-induction-that-a-in-a-1-triangle-a-2-triangle-ldots-triangle?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a proof that I feel is more intuitive.  First of all, define the XOR ("exclusive or") operator $\oplus$ as follows:
$$
p \oplus q\overset{\text{ def}}{\iff} (\lnot p \land q) \lor (p \land \lnot q).
$$
Thus, $\triangle$ is defined by
$$
x \in A_1 \triangle A_2 \iff (x\in A_1) \oplus (x\in A_2).
$$
With that, the key is to see that $\oplus$ is really [addition modulo $2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).  In particular, here is a table for addition modulo 2 and a truth table for $\oplus$:
$$
\begin{array}{c|cc}
+ & 0 & 1\\
\hline 
0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \qquad 
\begin{array}{c|cc}
\oplus & F & T\\
\hline 
F & F & T\\
T & T & F
\end{array}
$$
In other words, the identification $F \mapsto 0$, $T \mapsto 1$ is an isomorphism of [abeliean groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group).  Thus, evaluating the statement
$$
x \in A_1 \triangle A_2 \triangle \cdots \triangle A_n
$$
amounts to evaluating
$$
[[(x \in A_1) \oplus (x_1 \in A_2)] \oplus \cdots \oplus (x \in A_n)],
$$
which is equivalent to evaluating the sum
$$
[[x_1 + x_2] + \cdots + x_n]
$$
modulo $2$ where $x_i$ is $0$ if $x \notin A_i$ and $1$ if $x \in A_i$.  In other words, the result is true iff $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$ is equal to $1$ modulo $2$, which is to say that $x_1 + \cdots + x_n$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_x: (\mathcal{P}(E), \Delta) \to (\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}, +)$ be defined by
$$
f_x(A) = \begin{cases}
1 &\text{if $x \in A$} \\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
It is easy to see that $f_x(A \Delta B) = f_x(A) + f_x(B)$. In other words, $f_x$ is a semigroup morphism. It follows that $f_x(A_1 \Delta \dotsm \Delta A_n) = 1$ if and only if $x$ belongs to an odd number of $A_i$'s.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome.